# How to truncate long file path in vim-powerline statusline?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, statusline, vim-powerline

I would like to truncate my file path to ex: `a/a/j/c/popularCategories.js`.

[image: my powerline status]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options.

Try this option:

```
    let g:Powerline_stl_path_style = 'short'
```

From the powerline docs:

> ```
> short      Display a short path. The home directory is substituted with
>            "~", the first directory is displayed with its full name, and
>            subsequent directories are shortened to their first letter.
>            I.e. "/home/user/foo/bar/baz.vim" becomes "~/f/b/baz.vim" and
>            "long/relative/path/foo/bar/baz.vim becomes
>            "long/r/p/f/b/baz.vim".
> ```

Or, if you want the path truncated like Vim's default statusline, then you can create a theme that [moves the truncation point](https://github.com/pydave/powerline-sanity/commit/f3cec318194d73241c2da33a82385182ead4da53). Try my [sanity theme](https://github.com/pydave/powerline-sanity) and see if it works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

<s>There is currently no way to do this.</s> I’ve missed this option somehow. There is an issue for changing the way powerline truncates path: [issue 215](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/issues/215), not to add truncation like I used to think.